# How to execute a class once and use the data in ASP.net page

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have the following class (`UCNewWorkFlow`) which calls a cache database and retrieves rows and adds it to a string array:

```
public partial class UCNewWorkflow : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string Connectioncacha = "";

    public UCNewWorkflow()
    {
        int temp;

        if (IsItWorkDay(DateTime.Now))
        {
            temp = 21;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 17;
        }

        try
        {
            CacheConnection CacheConnect = new CacheConnection();
            CacheConnect.ConnectionString = Connectioncacha;
            CacheConnect.Open();

            String SQLtext = @"";

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            CacheCommand Command = new CacheCommand(SQLtext, CacheConnect);
            CacheDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
            string[] inArr = new string[4];
            int k = 0;

            if (Reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    inArr[k] = Reader["NotYetSeen"].ToString();
                    returnTime(Convert.ToInt32(inArr[k]));
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
        }
    }

    public string returnTime(int inHowMany)
    {
        string strTime = "";

        double future = 0;

        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        if (inHowMany / 2.0 <= 1)
        {
            strTime = "15 mins";
        }
        else if (inHowMany == 0)
        {
            strTime = "<15 mins";
        }
        else if (inHowMany / 2.0 > 1)
        {
            future = Math.Ceiling((inHowMany / 2.0)) * 15;

            DateTime tempdate = dt.AddMinutes(future);

            TimeSpan result = tempdate - DateTime.Now;

            strTime = ToReadableString(result);
        }

        return strTime;
    }
}
```

The result of the SQL query:

[image]

I have the following labels in my ASP.net page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstRow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblSecondRow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblThirdRow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblFourthRow" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

The code-behind for the ASP.net page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UCNewWorkflow uc = new UCNewWorkflow();
}
```

At the moment, I can't access the label from the class file.

How can I modify the code so, I have to call the class once and it will populate all four labels.

Comment: if you are going to post code.. please post the full code in regards to the issue at hand.. for example if the code above belongs to a Class.. then show the full Class / Code.. also `string[] inArr = new string[4];` I would create a Class within your current class to depict the object(s) / structure that you are trying to store information. I would make those fields in that class `auto properties with `{get; set;}` what are you doing once you create an instance of `UCNewWorkFlow()` with `us`

Comment: [C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_classes.htm)

Comment: @MethodMan Sorry, I updated my question with the class.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to perform this database query during the page's constructor, so it is too early in the ASP.NET Web Forms page lifecycle to have access to those arrays. Those labels do not exist when your constructor is called; they are created during the page initialization event.

As NicoTek suggested, using the Page_Load event handler is a good way of updating these labels. However, if you do it his way, I do not see a reason why your class is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page, I would recommend refactoring your code so that this and any other database operations exist in another class. This will allow you to reuse code and prevent clutter and repetition in your code-behind files.

Comment: That is where I would like some assistance please. The class isn't returning anything, the function in the class returns a string.

Comment: 1) Modify your class not to inherit from page.
2) Consider making different methods for data access options instead of using the constructor so that this class can handle all of your database operations.
3) From an ASP.NET page, create your class and call the data methods inside the Page_Load event handler.

To conceptually understand this better, I would recommend researching what a Data Access Layer is. A good pattern to use in Web Forms to separate concerns(data model, business logic, display logic) is Model View Presenter, that may help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you want to return the string array `inArr` as a property of your `UCNewWorkflow` class and then bind this to a repeater on the Page_Load of your code-behind as suggested by @NicoTek.

Your `Repeater` definition on the code-in-front should contain just one `Label` definition and then as data is bound to the `Repeater` a new instance of the label is created for each element in your string array.

More details on repeaters can be found at 
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UCNewWorkflow uc = new UCNewWorkflow();
    lblFirstRow.Text = "someString"
}
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.